# jquery fade in multiple imgs at multiple speeds on scroll-over

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to use the a jquery plugin ([jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/BP6rq/)) and it works great when I use it as intended, adding a class to imgs.

What I would like to have is a page in which multiple images appear upon scroll-over but at slightly different fadein speeds, so that a cluster group of images don't all fade in at once but kind of popping-popcorn-effect in.

```
tiles = $("ul#tiles li").fadeTo(0, 0);

$(window).scroll(function(d,h) {
    tiles.each(function(i) {
        a = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();
        b = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
        if (a < b) $(this).fadeTo(500,1);
    });
});
tiles = $("ul#tiles2 li").fadeTo(0, 0);

$(window).scroll(function(d,h) {
    tiles.each(function(i) {
        a = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();
        b = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
        if (a < b) $(this).fadeTo(1000,1);
    });
});tiles = $("ul#tiles3 li").fadeTo(0, 0);

$(window).scroll(function(d,h) {
    tiles.each(function(i) {
        a = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();
        b = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
        if (a < b) $(this).fadeTo(1500,1);
    });
});
```

I've tried using the javascipt multiple times with different classes and respective fadein times (example of this above), then assigning those different classes to the different images, but whichever class is the last one listed (in the case above #tiles3) is the only one that works. Any advice appreciated.

thanks, 
Nick

Answer (score 0):

You are changing `tiles`, but the scroll happens after that. If you want it localized to each scroll, you need to do this (for example):

```
$('#tiles,#tiles2,#tiles3').find('li').fadeTo(0, 0);
$(window).scroll(function(d,h) {
    $("#tiles li").each(function(i) {
        a = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();
        b = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
        if (a < b) $(this).fadeTo(500,1);
    });
});
```

Or give them different names. Every time a scroll happens, it's using the current `tiles` variable rather than the one right above the code.

Comment: Thanks Kalley! I tried this and, perhaps because I'm using it on images rather than list items, the effect was that rather than simply fading in, they faded in and then blinked on and off interminably.  Not what I was going for...but cool looking.

Comment: It appears to work fine here when used with images: http://jsfiddle.net/BP6rq/821/